# One sided dist-free tolerance intervals and testing

Tags: sample-size, tolerance-interval

I am involved in writing a standard where test labs are trying to decide sample sizes for a new device.

The suggestion has been that using ISO 16269-6: Table F.1 ("sample size for a proportion *p* at confidence level $1-\alpha$") that selecting $1-\alpha=0.95$ and $p=0.95$, giving a sample size of 59.  You can do the calculation with the 'tolerance' package:

```
distfree.est(alpha=0.05,P=0.95,side=1)
```

Am I correct in my interpretation of this - that if we test 59 devices and none of them fail, that gives us confidence (at a 0.05 level) that 95% of the production run is compliant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close: 59 is the smallest sample size for which observing no defects would allow you to reject (at a significance level of 5%) the hypothesis that 95% or less of the production run is compliant. So if you test 59 devices and none of them fail, the one-sided 95% confidence interval for the proportion compliant over the run does not include values of 95% or lower. The assumption is that the number of defects has a binomial distribution - reasonable if defects occur independently at a constant probability over each run, & if the sample is a small fraction of the total run.

Comment: Yes - of course - that makes sense.  Thanks for your rapid reply.

Comment: Note that, if you want to do the sums in your head instead of in R, for 95% confidence intervals only, the required sample size is well approximated as $\frac{3}{p}$.

Comment: Neat!  But why use my head when I can use R ?  ;-)